# Подпись на Push-уведомления с сервера FCM в java приложении

Tags: java, firebase, push-уведомления

Сервер приложения компании работает с FCM и уведомления приходят в их андроид приложение. А я бы хотел подписаться на push-уведомления в java приложении, которое я запускаю под виндой. Возможно ли это? Вариант установить эмулятор андроид на комп и пользоваться андроид приложением не подходит. Неужели нельзя java приложение заставить подписаться на уведомления и обрабатывать их как мне угодно? Нужен ответ возможно ли это и направление в котором копать

Answer (score 0):

Если вы не хотите ставить эмулятор - тогда вам нужно самостоятельно разработать приложение(читай среду), которое будет реализовывать задуманный вами функционал. Приложение, написанное под андройд, использует логику данной ОС, и получать пуш-уведомления можно только через это приложение.